# Strange behaviour in windows powershell

Tags: powershell

How to terminate `>>` sign in windows powershell console

Answer (score 3):

It's expecting you to continue an un-finished statement that you entered, or provide other input. This isn't "strange" behavior, it's completely expected.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to cancel out of the `>>`.

Comment: Backspace won't help unless you're using PSReadline.

Comment: @Jason, oh, right. I forgot I had that. I will edit my answer. Does ctrl+c still work?

Answer (score 0):

Hit enter twice to go down two rows

Comment: Usually that won't help.

Comment: Hmm, I kinda assumed OP is copy/pasting something but of course it is possible that he as an unclosed quote, parenthesis etc., and PowerShell may be pointing that out... I should probably change the answer to point out the other cases but not sure 'that short' question deserves more time